# Github Pages - Maintaining Multiple versions

Tags: github, github-pages

I need to host the documentation of multiple versions of my project (say 1.0, 2.0 and 3.0) and all are active (documentation)branches and we shall keep on adding improvements to all of these. 
Is it possible to use GitHub pages for this purpose?

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Can't you just use top-level directories within pages?

Answer (score 8):

This is feasible using [Github Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) along with a static site generator (SSG) of your choice such as [VuePress](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/), [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/), [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) etc.

In its simplest form, create a GH action to generate the static site folder of the branch/release, then push the folder to corresponding folder in the branch pointed to by GH pages, say *gh-pages*. One of the branches/releases should be pushed to root. [GitHub Pages Deploy Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-to-github-pages) can be helpful. Lastly add a dropdown list of versions to your static website pointing to the matching folder. The list of items can be statically maintained or dynamically populated using GitHub API. The selected item depends on the current URL path.

Example:

To provide multi-version docs for software product *NotifyBC*, of which docs and code are in the same repo,

- input - [docs](https://github.com/bcgov/NotifyBC/tree/main/docs) folder of the product created by VuePress
- output - [gh-pages](https://github.com/bcgov/notifybc/tree/gh-pages) branch
- [GitHub action](https://github.com/bcgov/NotifyBC/blob/main/.github/workflows/ghPages.yml), with *main* branch pushed to root of *gh-pages* branch and releases pushed to *version* folder. At the time when a version falls out of support, just manually delete it from the the *version* folder.
- [dynamically populated dropdown list implemented in Vue component](https://github.com/bcgov/NotifyBC/blob/main/docs/.vuepress/components/versions.vue)
- [rendered site](https://bcgov.github.io/NotifyBC/)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [gh-pages-multi](https://github.com/koumoul-dev/gh-pages-multi).

It is a small nodejs tool I wrote to push different versions of docs to subdirectories in a gh-pages branch. It also generates a index.html file listing those subdirectories.

It is fairly easy to integrate in a CI workflow if you want to automate building and pushing the docs.

Also note the "--no-history" option that will prevent bloating the git repo if your docs contain some built files or binary assets.

Answer (score 1):

These other answers over-complicate things. As @jhpratt suggests in the comment, you can just copy the code corresponding to a version of your site you want to deploy to a dir (labelled e.g. `v1.0`) within the dir that you deploy to gh-pages. You then access the version with `https://your-name.github.io/your-repo/v1.0/`.

Of course, depending on the type of site you're building you may have to worry about the content of `<base href="...">` tag, etc., for each version, but you need to worry about this tag in any case since github pages do not deploy to the url root.